# Bijection between $\Bbb R$ and $S^1$?

Tags: calculus

I need to find a bijection  between $\Bbb R$ and $S^1=\{x \in \Bbb R^2 : |x|=1\}$. I know a bijection from $[0,1)$ to $S^1$ given by $t \mapsto (\cos 2\pi t, \sin 2\pi t)$, so I think I have to find a bijection from $\Bbb R$ to $[0,1)$.

Comment: Continuous? No. Just a function, yes - both sets are uncountable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does a bijection $S^1 := \{ (x,y): x^2 + y^2 = 1\} \to \mathbb{R}$ exists?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2963055/does-a-bijection-s1-x-y-x2-y2-1-to-mathbbr-exists)

Answer (score 4):

Do you know a bijection between $\Bbb R$ and $(0,1)$?  This is not hard because the ends are open in both cases.  Then just shift a bunch of points to close off the end, so $$\begin {cases} f(1/2)=0\\ f(1/n)=1/(n-1)&n \in \Bbb N, n\gt 2\\ f(x)=x & \text{otherwise} \end {cases}$$ is a bijection from $(0,1)$ to $[0,1)$