# Does a bijection $S^1 := \{ (x,y): x^2 + y^2 = 1\} \to \mathbb{R}$ exist?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, circles, real-numbers

This is a question I encountered on the first Linear Algebra Exercise sheet of a friend, who just started studying maths. I have already completed basic modules like linear algebra and analysis, but was stumped by this question.

> Find a surjective mapping $\mathbb{R} \to S^1$.
>   Does there exists a injective mapping $\mathbb{R} \to S^1$?

Easily, $f: \mathbb{R} \to S^1, \ x \mapsto \left(\cos(x), \sin(x) \right)$ is a surjective mapping, but I having trouble finding a function which is also injective and also simple, since a maths beginner should (dis)prove the second question.

I am also interested how such a bijective mapping would look like.

Comment: For an injective map try removing one point from the circle, can you find a bijection from this set with the real line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A standard example is$$\begin{array}{ccc}f\colon&\mathbb R&\longrightarrow&S^1\\&x&\mapsto&\displaystyle\left(\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2},\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\right).\end{array}$$It is injective and it range is $S^1\setminus\bigl\{(-1,0)\bigr\}$.

Comment: How do I show it's injectivity with beginner's methods? Since both $x \mapsto \frac{1 - x^2}{1 + x^2}$ and $x \mapsto \frac{2x}{1 + x^2}$ are not injective...

Comment: The first component is strictly increasing on $(-\infty,0]$ and strictly decreasing on $[0,+\infty)$. It is also an even function. Therefore, could only fail to be injective if there was a $x\neq0$ such that $f(x)=f(-x)$. But the second component is an odd function.

Comment: Could you please share some insight or intuition on how one could found this function or a similar one satisfying the needed properties.

Comment: For each point $p$ on $S^1\setminus\bigl\{(-1,0=\bigr\}$, consider the line defined by $p$ and by $(-1,0)$. That line intersects the $y$ axis at a single point $(0,y)$. Then $p=f(y)$. In other words, $f$ is the inverse of the stereographic projection of $S^1$ onto the $y$ axis.

Comment: I just found out that if you use $x = \tan \left(\frac{t}{2} \right)$, your function $f$ becomes $(\cos(t), \sin(t))$!

Answer (score 2):

The following answers the question in the title and on the last line of your post.

For topological reasons a bijective map $f:\>S^1\to{\mathbb R}$ can only be obtained using some trickery. Note that $S^1$ is compact, but ${\mathbb R}$ is not. As a consequence there is no continuous map $f:\>S^1\to{\mathbb R}$ which is surjective. It follows that we cannot set up a simple expression defining a map having all desired properties.

Here is an example which I made up ad hoc; maybe there are simpler constructions: Beginning with $z_0:=(1,0)$ choose an infinite sequence of distinct points $z_k$ along $S^1$ such that after one full turn the $z_k$ converge to $(1,0)$ "from the other side". These $z_k$ partition $S^1$ into infinitely many half-open arcs $[z_{k-1},z_k[^{\rm (arc)}\>$ $(k\geq1)$. Map the first of these arcs bijectively onto $[0,1[\>\subset{\mathbb R}$, the second onto $[{-1},0[\>$, the third onto $[1,2[\>$, the next onto $[{-2},{-1}[\>$, and so on.

Comment: Could you explain those topological reasons please?

Answer (score 1):

Since $S^{1}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ have the same cardinal, there exits a bijection between $S^{1}$ and $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Hello! You are true, but that should have been a comment to the question.

Comment: @Taladris I don't see why it should be a comment - it answers the question perfectly.

Comment: @lisyaus sorry, Taladris is answering another question.

Comment: I don't know but it just exists. to construct such a bijection is also not difficult. For example, $Z(\theta)=\exp({\bf i}\theta)$ is bijection between $S^1$ and $[0,2\pi)$. And then, it is easy to find a bijection between $\mathbb{R}$ and $[0,2\pi)$ by functions like $\tan$, $\arctan$

Comment: @lisyarus: I was speaking about the answer before it was edited. No I am fine with this answer.